# API Platform - Authorization (403) before data handling (404)

Tags: api-platform.com

When performing GET item operation on unauthorized endpoint:

Why API Platform throws 404 exception when the id of resource does not exist in database?

There was a debate in 2019 about that and it seems like they did well and made security work before deserialization but actually not the way I prefer which is to prevent access to resource before asking database about it.

IMHO It's performance and security **leak** because you call database when not needed and expose the information whether the resource is inside the database or not!
But even that let's say developers don't care about leaks it would be really nice to give others opportunity to handle security stuff before handling other data flow scenarios.

There is no need to end user to know that resource does not exist when he has no permission for it. Meanwhile API Platform allows to see 404 error when the access should be denied (403) instead during request to nonexistent resource or row in table (call it however you like.. it's the same).

How to prevent access (403) to the nonexistent resource instead of getting 404 code in response?

PS: 403 in API Platform works as expected when resource exists.

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered multiple times.

> Why API Platform throws 404 exception when the id of resource does not exist in database?

API-Platform allows developers to [write security rules](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/security/#security) like the following one:

```php
@ApiResource(
  ...
  security = object.owner == user
)
```

`object` is the instance targeted by current HTTP request. So, when performing GET requests, API-Platform **needs** to `read` then `deserialize` the `object` before making the comparison. Perhaps *your* specific use case does not require it, but it does for most of the other API.

> IMHO It's performance [...] leak

It is indeed an useless operation in *your* use case.

> [...] security leak [...] expose the information whether the resource is inside the database or not!

Since a huge part of API-Platform's security may rely on [Doctrine Extension](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/security/#filtering-collection-according-to-the-current-user-permissions), API-Platform may returns `404` HTTP response ( or filtered collections on `GET collection` operations) when the **current user** is not allowed to see the targeted resource.
So `404` does not mean that the targeted object does not exist, it means that it does not exist for the current user, which increase opacity because an attacker *never* know if the resource does not exist or if he is not allowed to see it.
There is absolutely no security leak.

> How to prevent access (403) to the nonexistent resource instead of getting 404 code in response?

You may implement an [`EventSubscriberInterface`](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/events/#custom-event-listeners) to execute your security rules before the `ReadListener` i.e. `BEFORE_READ`. Perhaps `access_control` rules inside the `security.yaml` file are enough. You did not specify your use case at all so I don't know.

To conclude, that kind of complain about the framework implementation should be reported directly to API-Platform's [github](https://github.com/api-platform/core), not here.

Comment: I don't see the need of creating an `object` by API Platform... I only want to use some UserInterface object created by authenticator like this: 
`security: 'user.hasRole("myrole")'`.
You just assume too much just to justify the API Platform.
I don't need to call database and check if my resource as you called `object` has some kind of `owner`. All I need is to check if my user has a role - if not then deny the access.
It's very simple and this is how security should work which is to give a response of 403 when logged in user don't have correct role. If he does then check for existence...

Comment: So I guess I need to create event subscriber to deny the access before unwanted code is executed.

API Platform is leaking informations about resource existence if you don't want deserialization of so called `object`. When you check only role then after calling the endpoint with bad id and any role you get the 404 and when you call it with good id and bad role then it's 403. It's 100% leak that forces you to create such event subscriber.
Since only role check is the standard Symfony approach I'm very disappointed to discover the situation on my own without any suggestions anywhere.

Comment: You missed the point of my entire answer. You asked why API-Platform fetch the object before checking security rules, and I have explained to you why. What I have told you has been confirmed by API-Platform team, period.